# MAMP (OS X 10.10 beta 2) Apache not starts (httpd cannot be opened)

Tags: apache, mamp

I got just the new public beta 2 of OS X 10.10 and MAMP stopped to work. No way to start the apache server, port 80 or 8080, always error: httpd cannot be opened...

In the first public beta MAMP worked correctly. Found with Google some advice: Rename the file “envvars” located in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin into “_envvars” and this is not working at all.

Any idea on how to fix that?

Answer (score 9):

Renaming the `envvars` file in `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin` worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me when I was getting this error: `dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
  Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
 in /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl: line 80: 20269 Trace/BPT trap: 5       $HTTPD -k $ARGV
`

Answer (score 1):

I find it odd that the "_envvars" solution works for some folks, but not for others. As I mentioned in a previous post, the minute I made that small file name change, MAMP PRO's Apache server started running again.

I should note that the problem didn't start for me until after I installed Yosemite DP5 over top of Yosemite Public Beta 1. Or maybe it was when I installed Yosemite DP6 over top of DP5. Whatever the case may be, this fix did work for me.

Maybe it has something to do with your specific OS configuration, or the particular machine that you are using.

Comment: I do not run DPx versions, I have public beta 2 released yesterday. I did 
a) install 3.05 over 3.04 -> Not working. b) uninstalled MAMP completely, and re-installed 3.05 -> Not working. c)

Comment: c) tried several port combination, no error logs, then I noted that a crash report is generated when I try to start the MAMP page (Symbol not found: _iconv , so I renamed _envvars and back to its original name and each time the crash report shows the same. Anything I should check to test and post here?

Comment: I have now AMPPS installed, it works fine, no problems at all. Only the way to setup it I doesn't like much. Will keep MAMP in parallel, and return to work with MAMP when the above problem is fixed.